# R - randomly picking columns to sum up row values

Tags: r, loops, simulation

I have a dataset with 20 columns and 1000 rows generated using:

```
sim_data <- do.call(cbind, replicate(20, rexp(1000, 1/120), simplify = FALSE))
```

How can I pick a random number of columns per row to add up their values, and have a column indicating how many columns were picked?

I have:

```
picked <- sim_data[sample(nrow(sim_data), 5)]
sim_data$Sum <- sum(picked)
sim_data$Number <- length(picked)
```

but how do I pick a random size from 1 to 20, instead of "5", and repeat over all rows?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply`

```
cbind(sim_data, t(apply(sim_data,1, function(x) {
       i1 <- sample(seq_along(x), 1)
       out <- sum(sample(x, i1))
       c(Length = i1, Sum = out)
     }
        )))
```

Comment: thanks that works. now how do I add a column indicating how many values were picked (i.e. the sample size)?

Comment: @N.J here, it is 5 values per row.  Are you taking different values per row

Comment: @N.J.  If you want to create a size column `sim_data$size <- 5`

Comment: oh then this does not answer my dilemma. I need it to pick a random number from 1 to 20, not 5. 5 was an example.